# No Ubuntu choice on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Ubuntu 20.04 was working on my laptop, then I divided SSD into two partitions, then installed windows10 to new partition and working well, now, while startup it should ask for which OS should be run, but it automatically starting Windows.

Things I have tried:

1. Tried this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zegpROLecgc&t=3s&ab_channel=ASATechnical)  and run: bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \efi\ubuntu\boot\grubx64.efi , and it showed "The operation completed successfully"
2. Changed three times in BIOS setting - legacy boot only, UEFI boot only, Boot both, but nothing changed, it's still starting Windows, then I leave this for Boot both.

I searched a lot, no solutions found

Comment: You never ran grub update? Read this https://itsfoss.com/update-grub/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure whether it is UEFI or MBR boot.

1. After that create a bootable Ubuntu usb.
2. Boot from this usb.
3. Next open the terminal from Live CD and mount the partition where the previous installation of Ubuntu was.

```
mkdir -p mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt
chroot /mnt
```

4. First check if it is enabled in grub. From `/etc/default/grub` change the line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

5. After making sure you are in the previous installation, install `os-prober` so that grub recognizes the Windows installation.

```
sudo apt install os-prober
```

6. Update grub and reboot

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should be able to see both partitions on startup.